# iOS Flutter dark mode not changing instantly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, ios-darkmode

I'm not sure if this is a flutter issue, but whenever i change light/dark mode from control center, the theme does not change instantly. Only after dismissing the control center and resume back the app, then it will start to change. I have uploaded a gif to explain the issue.

If i compare to other apps like Reddit, the background will instantly change to dark after toggling dark mode in control center

[image: Flutter toggle light dark mode]

For now im using the default material app theme

**main.dart**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      home: HomeWidget()
    );
  }
```

**AppTheme.dart**

```
class AppTheme {

  AppTheme._();

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
      canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
      textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
          headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
      ),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black
      ),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light),
      brightness: Brightness.light
  );

  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
      canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff111215),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffd0d2d4)),
          caption: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff717579)),
          headline6: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffd0d2d4))
      ),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Color(0xff9aa0a6)
      ),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light),
      brightness: Brightness.light
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think that there isn't a way of evading this at this stage because flutter is "not looking for changes" when the control center is open because it's working in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking it in the debugging mode or release mode. If you are checking it in the debugging mode just check it in the release mode(debug mode renders a little slow).

Let me know if it works